# Eliminating sequences in a message

Tags: algorithm, checksum, crc, error-detection, hamming-distance

I have an odd communications channel, and I need to detect errors as well as eliminate certain sequences in the channel.

Each message is 12 bits long, split into 3 nibbles (of 4 bits each). I need to extract at least 450 different codes out of this, so I can have a hamming distance of up to 3.

However, I cannot have two nibbles in sequence be the same, so the following sequences are invalid:

```
0xf 0xf 0xf - Three of the same nibbles in sequence
0x8 0x8 0x0 - Two of the same nibbles in sequence
0xf 0x3 0x3 - Two of the same nibbles in sequence
```

Further, messages can follow each other without breaks, so the beginning of one sequence can't have the same first nibble as the end of the last sequence:

```
0x327 0x743 - Even though they are not in the same message, two sequential nibbles are the same in the message stream
```

But the following sequences are fine:

```
0x1 0x2 0x1 - Two nibbles same, but separated by another nibble
0x0 0x1 0x2 - All nibbles different
0xf 0x8 0x3 - All nibbles different
```

And the following series of messages is fine:

```
0x121 0x012 0xf83 - No two adjacent nibbles are the same is the stream of messages
```

My first thought is to use 9 bits for my message, split into three 3 bit parts as the top bits of each nibble:

```
mmmc mmmc mmmc - Each character is a bit, m bits are message, c bits are checksum/parity/etc
```

Then design a 512 entry table that gives me the three bits to fill `c` with that will create the hamming distance while eliminating the troublesome sequences.

However, this will be running on a low end embedded processor, and if I can use arithmetic to generate the `c` bits on the fly, it will save memory (in exchange for more processor time) which is more valuable in this case.

**Is there a bit of math I can perform that would solve this problem without a table?**

**Alternately, is there another packing method with math that would meet the requirements?**

Comment: "At least 450 codes"?  How many codes do you need to represent at most?

Comment: @MarkAdler There is no upper bound - I'll take as many codes as I can get that still meets the requirements.

Comment: I do not believe that there exists a set of 450 12-bit code words with a Hamming distance of no less three for any pair.  So if that's your requirement, I think that that's impossible.

Comment: @MarkAdler You are probably right, which is why I said "up to 3".  With 11 bits and a hamming distance (minimum) of 3 you can get 128 codewords: http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/hamming.pl?X=+Generate+&L=11&D=3&T=00000000000 and with 12 bits and a minimum hamming distance of 4 you can get 128 codewords.  Unfortunately this generator complains that there are too many if you attempt to calculate the number of codewords available in a 12 bit message with a minimum hamming distance of 3.  It's possible that it's as high as 450, but as you can tell I'm not intimately familiar with this theory.

Comment: As far as I can tell (someone correct me if I'm wrong) a 12 bit word with a hamming distance of 3 has a possible total of 256 codewords.  So in this case a hamming distance of up to 2 would be appropriate.

Comment: Judging by "non-equal adjacent" condition, you are working with DTMF signals.  In that case, bitwise hamming distance doesn't fit well to your task.  Digit-wise hamming distance would be better.  If you want to have digit-wise hamming distance of 2, then no more than 64 codes would be available (8 variants for left digit, 8 variants for right, unique middle digit due to hamming distance of 2).  Are 64 codes enough for you?

Comment: I did a quick search and could find no more than 256 12-bit words with a Hamming distance of 3.  I'm sure that there's a reference out there for exhaustive searches to say what that number is.  I'm sure that if it's more than 256, it's much less than 450.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff's comment is correct.  I didn't see a mention of the modulation before.  You should consider longer codewords than three signal changes for the purposes of error correction.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff You are partly right.  I'm actually working with 17 tones.  They aren't dual tones, but the conclusion you provide that bit-wise hamming distance is the wrong tool is correct.  I'm not looking for error correction right now, just error detection.  However, I'm using web audio which does have provisions for precise timing, meaning that I might actually be able to have a clock and eliminate the non-sequential requirements.  But for this simple proof-of-concept I'm using typical javascript timing functions which are, at best, poor for mS resolution sequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The simplest method:*
0mmm 1mmm 0mmm - no repeating nibbles, fastest encoding/decoding, no checksum

*But I'd recommend the following method:*
You have 3600 = 16*15*15 possible nibble triplets (first nibble has 16 variants, second has 15, third has 15).
You can have 2 bits for checksum and 3600/4 = 900 domain-specific codes.

Encoder (decoder is the reverse of it):

```
C = 0..899 -- your code to be encoded  
C = C * 4  -- appending a "hidden checksum"
N3 = C mod 15  -- 0..14
C = C div 15
N2 = C mod 15  -- 0..14
N1 = C div 15  -- 0..15
nibble1 = N1
nibble2 = (nibble1 + 1 + N2) mod 16
nibble3 = (nibble2 + 1 + N3) mod 16
```

Dividing by 15 is as simple as multiplying by 0.000100010001<sub>2</sub> if you haven't DIV operation.

Decoder:

```
nibble1, nibble2, nibble3 -- your three nibbles
N1 = nibble1
N2 = (nibble2 - nibble1 - 1) mod 16
N3 = (nibble3 - nibble2 - 1) mod 16
C = (N1*15 + N2)*15 + N3
if C mod 4 != 0 then CHECKSUM ERROR
C = C/4  -- 0..899
```

---

**UPD** for new conditions:
no checksum, 8*14*8 = 896 possible codes

Encoder (decoder is the reverse of it):

```
C = 0..895 -- your code to be encoded  
N1 = C mod 8
C = C div 8
N2 = (C div 8) + 1 + N1
N3 = (C mod 8) + 8
if N2 >= N3 then N2 = N2 + 1
nibble1 = N1   -- 0..7
nibble2 = N2 mod 16
nibble3 = N3   -- 8..15
```

Decoder:

```
nibble1, nibble2, nibble3 -- your three nibbles (0..7, 0..15, 8..15)
N1 = nibble1
N2 = (nibble2 - nibble1 - 1) mod 16
N3 = nibble3
if N1 + N2 >= N3 then N2 = N2 - 1
C = (N2*8 + N3 - 8)*8 + N1  -- 0..895
```

Comment: I'm at somewhat of a loss understanding how you'd reverse the last two steps.  Would you mind being a little more explicit with the decoder, or at least writing the first few steps of it?

Comment: @AdamDavis - Appended to answer.

Comment: That's great!  Fortunately the encoder is on a high performance system, so the division isn't an issue there, and the multiplication on the low performance system for the decoder is easy enough.

Comment: Would you be able to provide guidance to a further modification of this problem? I'm trying to modify what you've provided so that the first and last nibbles are never the same.  I see that your algorithm already produces only even nibbles for `nibble3`, is there a minor modification that would force `nibble1` to be only odd?  I understand I'd lose over half the codes, but I still don't understand the math well enough to make the change myself.

Comment: I'll edit the question with an example of the new requirement so it's clear.  I'm also going to award you a bounty when I have that option, this is really helpful. I'll have to un-accept your answer so I have the bounty option available in two days.

Comment: @AdamDavis - `nibble3` may be odd.

Comment: Hm, I've put this algorithm in a spreadsheet to double-check it with all 900 possible input values, and I don't see any odd numbers in `nibble3`. I suppose I need to check my math...

Comment: Well, I've double checked everything and it looks right.  I too thought it was odd that `nibble3` never contained odd numbers, but if you run the algorithm through all 900 numbers and watch `nibble3` you'll find it never hits an odd number.  It outputs 0, 4, 8, and 12 105 times each, and 2, 6, 10, and 14 120 times each.

Comment: @AdamDavis - Yes, in the first encoder `nibble3` is always even.

Comment: It appears that the decoder for the second algorithm doesn't work.  I'm reversing the encoder right now to see if I can fix it, but perhaps you'd be faster at fixing it.  Try going through the encode and decode process for the value `1` and you get the answer 8.

Comment: @AdamDavis - I don't see a problem with 64.